# How To Filter SQL Results Efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to filter the table records based on passed input criteria to the SQL stored procedure. To make it simple, I'm elaborating the question using simple Employee table (I'm using MSSQL server for my project):

```
Table: Employee(Id, FirstName,LastName, Designation)
```

The stored procedure takes 3 input arguments (Id, LastName, Designation). This will be invoked with at-least one input parameter (other parameter will be set to empty string (in case of LastName, Designation) or 0 (In case of Id)).

Here is the stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure GetEmployees  
(  
   @id int,  
   @lastName  varchar(30),  
   @designation varchar(30)  
)   
  
AS  
  
BEGIN  
Create Table #employees (Id int, FirstName varchar(30),LastName varchar(30),   Designation varchar(30);  
  
IF(@id != 0)  
BEGIN  
Insert Into #employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,Designation)  
Select Id, FirstName,LastName,Designation From Employee Where Id = @id  
END  
  
IF(@lastName != ‘’)  
BEGIN  
Insert Into #employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,Designation)  
Select Id, FirstName,LastName,Designation From Employee Where LastName =  @lastName  
END  
  
IF(designation != ‘’)  
BEGIN  
Insert Into #employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,Designation)  
Select Id, FirstName,LastName,Designation From Employee Where Designation = @designation  
END  
  
-- Returning filtered record set to the application layer  
Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Designation From #employees;  
END   
  
GO
```

I think there a lot of code repetition in the stored procedure. Is there an efficient way of solving this scenario ?

Comment: Maybe just one insert with `where Id != '' or  LastName != '' or Designation  != ''`

Comment: This is a type of catch all query. Gail Shaw has written about this on her blog [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and then a follow up article [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Also read Erland Sommarskog's classic article here: http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Ah... you are talking about "coding efficiency" (the effort to write/change/debug the code), not database performance (the best use of server resources). Then, use an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a single insert query with a `WHERE` clause which covers all the logic:

```
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO #employees (Id, FirstName, LastName, Designation)  
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Designation
FROM Employee
WHERE
    (Id = @id AND @id <> 0) OR
    (LastName =  @lastName AND @lastName <> '') OR
    (Designation = @designation AND @designation <> '');
```

Comment: This can be a serious performance problem. See the article from Gail Shaw in my comments above. But this is definitely a very common way of handling this type of thing.

Comment: Given that a plain `select` follows in the OP's code, there is no need for the temporary table. Just `select` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Case` condition in `Where` clause, Find Below Query.

```
INSERT INTO #employees (Id, FirstName, LastName, Designation)  
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Designation
FROM Employee
WHERE
    (Id = CASE WHEN @id = 0 THEN ID ELSE @ID END) OR
    (LastName = CASE WHEN @lastName = '' THEN LastName ELSE @lastName END) OR
    (Designation = CASE WHEN @designation = '' THEN Designation ELSe @designation END);
```

We can also Use `AND` Instead of `OR` in `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As @trincot said, there is no need for a temporary table. My suggestion is:

```
Create Procedure GetEmployees  
(  
   @id int,  
   @lastName  varchar(30),
   @designation varchar(30)  
)   
AS  
BEGIN  
Select Id, FirstName,LastName,Designation From Employee 
Where (@id>''          AND Id = @id)
   OR (@lastName>''    AND LastName =  @lastName)
   OR (@designation>'' AND Designation = @designation);
END  

GO
```